# how to use one for loop key with another for loop key in django template

Tags: python, django

i able to print values from below code in django views

```
subMarks = []
for item in marks:
    for column in gridHeaderTableData:
        subMark = item[column['sub_exam_name']]
        subMarks.append(subMark)
```

how to write above code in django templates

Comment: Plz don't ask for code. Share what have you tried and where are you struggling.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the template?

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** set any variables in templates, it's actually not Python language. What is you **can do**, just write this code into your view, save result as variable, and push to your template, where you can print what you want.